# Upload newer version of strangers project to central maven repo

Tags: maven

`JBox2d` is at version `2.3.1-SNAPSHOT` ..

https://github.com/jbox2d/jbox2d/blob/master/jbox2d-library/pom.xml

However the latest version of the library at [Maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/) is `2.2.1.1` ..

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jbox2d/jbox2d-library

Is there a way that I can upload this newer version of `JBox2d` to the central repo for everyone's use?

Comment: Can you imagine the potential impact of being able to replace arbitrary projects under the same group/artifact IDs?! What happens when I replace commons-lang with my own version that randomly deletes files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no. Without the current maintainer's permission you can't upload a new artifact with the same `groupId`/`artifactId`. To quote from the [Guide to uploading artifacts to the Central Repository FAQ](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html#FAQ_and_common_mistakes):

> I have a patched version of the foo project developed at foo.com, what groupId should I use?
>
> When you patch / modify a third party project, that patched version becomes your project and therefore should be distributed under a groupId you control as any project you would have developed, never under com.foo. See above considerations about groupId.

Either pick a new `groupId`, for what is effectively your fork of the project, or collaborate with the current maintainers to get the newer version into Central with their permission.